# How to allow dynamic interface for a native JS trait in Scala 3?

Tags: scala, scala.js, scala-3

Following facade trait for three.js works fine with Scala 2:

```scala
@js.native
trait Uniforms extends js.Object with Dynamic {
  @JSBracketAccess
  def update(name: String, uniform: Uniform): Unit
  @JSBracketAccess
  def apply(name: String): Uniform

  @JSName("remove")
  def -=(name: String): Uniform

  @JSBracketAccess
  def selectDynamic(name: String): Uniform
  @JSBracketAccess
  def updateDynamic(name: String)(value: Uniform): Unit
}
```

It allows me to use uniforms both as `u("opacity").value = 0.5` and `u.opacity.value = 0.5`.

The trouble is it does not work with Scala 3. It compiles fine, but it produces an error in while linking (fastOptJS):

> [error] scala.Dynamic (of kind Interface) is not a valid interface implemented by threejs.Uniforms (of kind AbstractJSType)
>
> [error]   called from threejs.Uniforms

How can I define a facade for a native JS type in Scala 3 so that I can use it as `Dynamic` ? Deriving from  `js.Dynamic` is not possible, as it is `sealed`.

Comment: That's a bug in Scala 3. Please report it at https://github.com/lampepfl/dotty/issues/new/choose

Comment: Done in https://github.com/lampepfl/dotty/issues/19528

Comment: I guess fixing this will take some time - Scala 3 releases are not very frequent. It could be nice to know what options are there as a workaround until the fix is available.

Comment: I don't think there exists any workaround besides calling `u("opacity")` instead of `u.opacity`. In theory you could write a preprocessor for the IR generated for `Uniforms` to remove `scala.Dynamic` from its list of `interfaces`, but that is probably too much effort. Depending on your setup, you could also put `Uniforms.scala` in a Scala 2.13 project and depend on it from Scala 3 (this works, and is why `js.Dynamic` works in the first place from Scala 3).